# My app does not route in Internet explorer and Edge

Tags: angular, routes, internet-explorer-11, microsoft-edge

I have an angular project running in Chrome and it does not route in Internet Explorer or Edge. It gives an error as 
ReferenceError: 'TextEncoder' is undefined

I tried this and it worked for me

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/es6-object-assign@1.1.0/dist/object-assign-auto.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/text-encoding@0.6.4/lib/encoding.min.js"></script>
```

But I downloaded those packages using npm and it doesn't work.
es6-object-assign and
text-encoding

I want it to route in Internet explorer also. somebody please help

Comment: Have you tried adding polyfills ?

Comment: yes I enabled all polyfills related to IE

Comment: Can you demonstrate the problem with a stackblitz sample

Comment: It is difficult for me to demonstrate but still i tried to download the cdn script and tried to add locally

Comment: <script src="./js/encoding.js"></script>
  <script src="./js/object-assign-auto.js"></script>

Comment: Like above i added to index.html but still it does not work

Comment: You had mentioned that when you use those links it worked with IE but when you use the download version than it did not worked. Did you try to host your site and again try to check whether it work or not when the site is hosted on any server? If not, Than you can have a test and let us know about your testing result.